# ubuntu 18.10 fails to boot

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, 18.10

I spent many long hours trying to install Ubuntu 18.10 on AsRock computer. It installs fine even on a Intel NVME ssd that the motherboard's UEFI utility can not use as a boot device. The problem is that after the installation finishes, the operating system will not boot. I tried several different ways, several media devices (hdd, ssd), different partition schemes, but it will not boot properly, no matter what I try. When I use a live USB image, I can mount and use the root partition/s just fine. There's definitely something wrong with the installer.... It could not even boot from an install done on totally empty hard drive with no partitioning done by me, when I let the installer do everything by it's own.... This should not happen.... Ubuntu reputation will suffer if this kind of behavior continues... The question is... Why is this happening ? Also, how can I make it boot after partitioning and installing ?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of time spent on this issue I was able to get it resolved by downloading the newest Ubuntu 18.10 image, burn it to an USB stick and going again through the installation process, like I did many times before. It worked from the first try, but at this time I had a totally empty hard disk to use. I went through the custom partitioning myself and even instructed it to put the root partition on the Intel M2 SSD (mounted on a adapter that is connected to a PCIe port on an older motherboard). I made the rest of the Linux partitions on the hard drive, except "/usr" that I did not separate from the root mount point. I tried using swap this time. Also, had about 75 MB for the "bios boot reserved partition" and another 75-100 MB for the "EFI reserved boot partition" that were the first two partitions created on the hard drive, in that order. It worked this time. I suspect there something wrong with the previous installer and/or the handling of the two boot partitions mentioned previously (bios_boot and EFI).